# ZipArchive constructor in .NET framework v4.5.2 producing inconsistent results on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 and 2008 machines?

Tags: c#, .net

The ZipArchive Class in the .NET framework v4.5.2 is behaving differently on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 machines.

I have a sample `.APK` file from which I'm trying to construct a ZipArchive object as follows.

```
using(var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(File.OpenRead("sample.apk")))
{    
    Console.WriteLine("Number of Entries: "+ zipArchive.Entries.Count);
}
```

This works fine on a Windows 10 machine and no problems as expected because an `.APK` file is essentially a ZIP file.

However, trying to construct a ZipArchive object from the same file on a Windows Server 2012 and 2008 machine throws the exception "Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory".

Clearly, there is some underlying logic that is producing a false negative on the Windows Server machine as I was able to dissect the file and verify that the number of entries was indeed correct in the "End of Central Directory" section of the zip archive.

This indicates that the `System.IO.Compression` library is producing inconsistent results for the same file on different platforms and could be potentially problematic if that is actually the case.

Has anyone faced similar issues with other libraries provided by the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Every .NET Framework version 4.5+ is an *in-place upgrade*](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx). Therefore, if you are targeting version 4.5.2 when building, your application will use the highest version installed on the target machine above 4.5.2.

I suspect that the machines where it produces the error message have a different .NET Framework runtime version than the machine that works. If so, the simple solution is to update .NET Framework on the Windows Server 2012 and 2008 target machines (the latest .NET Framework version would probably be the best bet).

Comment: Based on this article (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx), libraries belonging to different .NET framework versions are stored under different folders under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework". Visual Studio knows about all the different versions of .NET and the compiler will reference different versions when you build. I don't think an inplace upgrade would make it unsafe to target a previous .NET framework version.

Comment: You were correct. I was able to solve the issue by installing .NET framework 4.6.2 on the WIndows server machine. Thank you.

Comment: `I don't think an inplace upgrade would make it unsafe to target a previous .NET framework version.` - No, but that doesn't mean there aren't bugs in some of them :). So, for anyone else who comes across this, what version did you upgrade from that had the bug in it?

Comment: The issue was with .NET 4.5.2. I later upgraded to .NET 4.6.2